# How to Send a file with TCP?

Tags: vb.net, tcp

I have been searching, and I cannot find any good examples of how to send a file with TCP. This is what I have tried so far:

```
Private Sub SendFile(FileName As String, Server As String, Port As Integer)
    Dim TcpClient As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient(Server, Port)
    Dim NetworkStream As System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream = TcpClient.GetStream()
    Dim Data() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(New System.IO.StreamReader(FileName).ReadToEnd())

    NetworkStream.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length)
    NetworkStream.Close()
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work. This is the code for the client:

```
Private Sub SendFile(FileName As String, Server As String, Port As Integer)
    Dim TcpClient As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient(Server, Port)
    Dim NetworkStream As System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream = TcpClient.GetStream()
    Dim FileStream As System.IO.Stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(FileName)
    Dim FileBuffer(FileStream.Length) As Byte

    FileStream.Read(FileBuffer, 0, FileStream.Length)
    NetworkStream.Write(FileBuffer, 0, FileStream.Length)
    NetworkStream.Close()
    FileStream.Close()
End Sub
```

And this is the code for the server:

```
Private Sub ReceiveFile(FileName As String, Port As Integer)
    Dim WorkerThread As New System.Threading.Thread(Sub()
                                                        Dim TcpListener As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, Port) : TcpListener.Start()
                                                        Dim HandlerSocket As System.Net.Sockets.Socket = TcpListener.AcceptSocket()

                                                        If HandlerSocket.Connected = True Then
                                                            Dim NetworkStream As New System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream(HandlerSocket)
                                                            Dim BlockSize As Integer = 1024
                                                            Dim DataRead As Integer
                                                            Dim DataByte(BlockSize) As Byte
                                                            Dim FileStream As System.IO.Stream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(FileName)

                                                            Do
                                                                DataRead = NetworkStream.Read(DataByte, 0, BlockSize)
                                                                FileStream.Write(DataByte, 0, DataByte.Length)

                                                                If DataRead = 0 Then
                                                                    Exit Do
                                                                End If
                                                            Loop
                                                            FileStream.Close()
                                                            NetworkStream.Close()
                                                        End If
                                                    End Sub)
    WorkerThread.Start()
End Sub
```